# Filtering long list of data from IEX

Tags: python, pandas, filter, elixir-iex

I would like to filter my data so that I only get the **symbol, close and sector**.

[image]

I tried using the code below but I get an error that ***'list is not callable'*** .

**Also, do note that iexfinance uses filter_, as filter is a reserved word in Python**

```
 print(losers(filter_=['symbol','close']))
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a **list** from `get_market_losers()` that you need to iterate over:

```
for loser in losers:
    print(loser["close"], loser["symbol"], loser["sector"])
```

Printout:

```
9.1  NEWA  Industrials
4.75 LCI   Healthcare
2.3  SN    Energy
8.51 SWZ   Financial Services
2.95 PES   Energy
8.1  EGAN  Technology
8.58 CIFS  Financial Services
1.76 GERN  Healthcare
1.03 BW    Technology
6.18 JILL  Consumer Cyclical
```

To get all your data in a dataframe use this (the columns are already named according to the IEX features):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(losers)
# printout transposed so that you see the long list of features
df.head(1).T
```

Printout:

```
avgTotalVolume      543967
calculationPrice    close
change              -0.36
changePercent       -0.03805
...
```

Filter from the dataframe directly:

```
df.loc[:, ["close", "symbol", "sector"]]
```

Printout:

[image]

Comment: OOHHH.. okie thanks so much Pete! btw just wondering if i will like to add a header above the results how do i go about doing that?

Comment: @Jonathan I am happy that this could help. See my edit for you additional question. Does that solve this?

Comment: @Jonathan If so I suggest you accept the answer so that others can see that your matter is solved. Have a great day!